# ionic 4 how to exit app with ios, navigator.app.exitApp not working

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic4

the commands:

```
navigator.app.exitApp()
navigator["app"].exitApp()
```

don't work with ios devices while they correctly work with android?

Thank you for help.

Comment: are you getting any error in your console?

Comment: Yes following is error:

⚡️  To Native ->  App exitApp -1
ERROR MESSAGE:  {"message":"not implemented","errorMessage":""}